# How to download all html page to excel using JavaScript (not just html table)

Tags: javascript, export

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx@0.15.1/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<span>MY LIST</span>
    <table id="tbl_exporttable_to_xls" border="1">
        <thead>
            <th>Sr</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Job Profile</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>
                    <p>Amit Sarna</p>
                </td>
                <td>Florida</td>
                <td>Data Scientist</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>
                    <p>Sagar Gada</p>
                </td>
                <td>California</td>
                <td>Sr FullStack Dev</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>
                    <p>Ricky Marck</p>
                </td>
                <td>Nevada</td>
                <td>Sr .Net Dev</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>
                    <p>Andrea Ely</p>
                </td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>Sr Delivery Mgr</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>
                    <p>Sunita Devgan</p>
                </td>
                <td>Colorado</td>
                <td>UiUx Expert</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button onclick="ExportToExcel('xlsx')">Export table to excel</button>

    <script>

        function ExportToExcel(type, fn, dl) {
            var elt = document.getElementById('tbl_exporttable_to_xls');
            var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(elt, { sheet: "sheet1" });
            return dl ?
                XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: type, bookSST: true, type: 'base64' }) :
                XLSX.writeFile(wb, fn || ('MySheetName.' + (type || 'xlsx')));
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm new in JavaScript. I want to export all html page to excel file(not just table) using JavaScript, example my code has
A title before table, and a button after table, I need export or convert title and table to excel with format as same html page format. But it just download table without my title.Please help me with example code, thanks much.

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement exactly, but seems there is a script that does the same [Export HTML tables to Excel using JavaScript](https://www.octoparse.com/blog/export-html-table-to-excel#a3)